# Python - Speed-up for loops - large data sets

Tags: python, arrays, performance, for-loop, large-data

I'm new in Python, and I need to speed-up this simple code.

I created this code in Matlab, and it runs "instantly".
I tried to 'convert' it in Python, but its very slow...

In my final code, this piece operation has to be looped thousand times...
So that at the end, this particular  part of the code needs to be as efficient as possible...

```
# a and B define the size of the data
a=9000  
b=4000
c=np.ones((a,))   # not one in my code
d=np.random.rand(a,b)  # not random in my code

res=np.zeros((b,1))  # pre-alloc

# here is the loop to be speed up !
tic = time.time()
for x in range(b):
    res[x]=sum(c*d[:,x])
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic)
```

Just to make it harder... In theory, "a" can be as big as 'millions'... and "b" as big a hundreds of thousands...
Not fun...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Binabik

Comment: Always think on standard operation (in this case vector-matrix product). In this case it is as simple as `res=np.dot(c,d).reshape(-1,1)` which takes approx. 10ms instead of 5s. (5000x faster)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, loops should be avoided while working with numpy arrays since numpy vectorized operations are much more efficient. This code gives the same result:

```
a=9000  
b=4000
c=np.ones((a,))
d=np.random.rand(a,b)
res=np.zeros((b,1))

# replaces the loop
(c*d.T).sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: yes, avoiding loops to perform actions on numpy arrays is good advice!

Comment: Good point.its 10x faster now ! Any solution to make it even faster ?
When using large "a" and "b", Python needs lots of RAM (and/or the code become slow), is there a way to optimize this ?

Comment: Note : working in float32 rather than 64 make it also twice faster.